# Discrete vs discretized signals

Tags: discrete-signals

Ive heard both of these terms and i am still having trouble to understand what is the difference between these two. As far as i understood, the only difference between discrete and discretized signal, is the x axis of it, for example if i have a single dirac at the $\Omega_0$ frequency it is considered to be discretized signal if its x axis has $\Omega$ as a variable

However, if we want to make this a discrete signal, we need to somehow manipulate the value on the x-axis (normally we should have n at the x axis if we want to have discrete signal).

I hope that question wasn't confusing. Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

What if i have a discretized signal, how am i supposed to make discrete signal out of it?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure I understand the question but it seems to be just a confusion of terms.

**Discrete**: A discrete time signal is one that is only defined at integer indices. Like you said, usually the notation for these indices are $n$.

**Discretize**: A discretized signal is one that is made to be discrete time. For example, if you have a continuous time signal, $x(t)$, and you sample it at some sampling period, $T$, you have discretized the signal and now have the discrete time signal $x[n]$.

Comment: I see, but what to do when i have a discrete frequency domain signal and i want to have discrete signal. Like, i have an infinite sum of dirac pulses in frequency domain and i have $\Omega$ at the x axis, how can i turn x axis in that case to be $n$?

Comment: You are wanting to go from the frequency domain to the time domain. This is done by the inverse discrete time fourier transform. Check out this pdf: http://pfister.ee.duke.edu/courses/ece485/dtft_table.pdf. It has the equations at the top and we often use these tables for the common ones like an impulse train as you described.